# UITableViewCell loaded with wrong traits variation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints, interface-builder

I have a UITableViewCell containing a UICollectionView with slightly different display between iPhone and iPad.

So some constraints are installed for iPhone (CR) but not for iPad (RR).
It seems that when the tableViewCell is displayed, it is with the last saved state of my xib, I mean:

- If I save the xib while I view it as IPad, my tableview will display correctly on iPad but not on iPhone
- If I save the xib while I view it as iPhone, my tableView will display correctly on iPhone but not on iPad

However if I scroll down to hide the cell and scroll up, the layout becomes OK.
Hope I have been clear enough.. What did I missed ?

[image: example of how my constraints are installed]

Comment: Try calling `layoutIfNeeded` in your `cellForItem`.

Comment: not working, I also tried that in willDisplayCell

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that. Perhaps you just won't be able to use this storyboard feature; you'll have to do the "different" layout yourself in code. I've had all kinds of issues with table view and collection view cells doing autolayout. As your question implies, it seems there's a problem with timing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try layoutIfNeeded() and layoutSubViews() in cellForItem,

maybe set height to 800 and use margin left right top left 0?

Answer (score 0):

Trait variations *should* work fine when using a Table View Cell in a xib.

If you don't often use them, though, it can be confusing.

Try this...

- create an empty xib
- add a table view cell
- add a label (with a background color to see it)

Constrain the label to the margins at Top: 0 / Leading: 0 / Bottom: 0 and give it a Width constraint of 160:

[image]

Now, select the Width constraint and, in the Size Inspector pane, click the `+` sign to the left of the Constant, and select `Width: Regular` and `Height: Any`:

[image]

... then click `Add Variation`:

[image]

Now change the `Constant` value for the new Trait variation to `600`:

[image]

Here's how it looks on an iPhone 8:

[image]

and on an iPad Pro 9.7:

[image]

To play with it, here's the code I used:

```
class TraitCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!
}

class TraitTestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TraitCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "traitCell")
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "traitCell", for: indexPath) as! TraitCell
        c.theLabel.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return c
    }
}
```

and here's the source for `TraitCell.xib`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17506" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17505"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="48" id="Lnk-lV-Xmf" customClass="TraitCell" customModule="DelMe" customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="48"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="Lnk-lV-Xmf" id="A7R-fE-SaJ">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="48"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="vB6-W5-Xl5">
                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="11" width="160" height="26"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.98977929350000005" green="0.91474151609999999" blue="0.16292566059999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="160" id="9U8-ws-UNn">
                                <variation key="widthClass=regular" constant="600"/>
                            </constraint>
                        </constraints>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                </subviews>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstItem="vB6-W5-Xl5" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="A7R-fE-SaJ" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="5GP-0t-6Zx"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="vB6-W5-Xl5" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="A7R-fE-SaJ" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="REV-Ua-5gO"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="vB6-W5-Xl5" secondAttribute="bottom" id="cF3-NH-NX1"/>
                </constraints>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="theLabel" destination="vB6-W5-Xl5" id="G7V-WZ-215"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="344" y="185.30734632683661"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
</document>
```